# WebView/WebEngine fails with GluonMobile, GraalVM22, JavaFX 17

Tags: javafx, webview, native, gluon, webengine

I built a simple app using WebView/WebEngine using Gluon Mobile but the WebView fails with a unsatisfiedlink error. It works fine with gluonfx:run and so I then ran gluonfx:runagent to get all the reflection stuff etc.  I then run gluonfx:build but the app fails on gluonfx:nativerun.  I have a simple fxml starting with <View fx:id="web"...> (with controller being WebPresenter) and containing a  containing a <VBox...> containing a <WebView fx:id="wv"...>.  The code is:

```
public class WebPresenter {
    @FXML View      web;
    @FXML WebView   wv;
    
    public void initialize() {           
        WebEngine we = wv.getEngine();
        we.loadContent("<html><body><h1>WebEngine!</h1></body></html>");
    }
}
```

I run the build with NetBeans on Ubuntu 20.04 64bit, JavaFX v17.0.2, Charm v6.1.0, Java 17, graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.0.0.3-Final.  The reflect-json seems to have all the Web stuff necessary: com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.web.WebViewBuilder, javafx.scene.web.WebView and WebPresenter.

The error occurs at load from the fxml <WebView...> and culminates in:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkInitWebCore(ZZZ)V [symbol: Java_com_sun_webkit_WebPage_twkInitWebCore or Java_com_sun_webkit_WebPage_twkInitWebCore__ZZZ]
:
at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:275)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.web.WebViewBuilder.build(WebViewBuilder.java:66)
```

I had WebView/WebEngine working under slightly earlier versions (GraalVM11 and javafx-web 17.0.0.1).  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I can reproduce it too. Filed https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/1137 to track it down.